# test for error thrown in node.js using mocha chai

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm new to node.js, and I'm having problems setting up a simple unit test for a function I expect to throw an error. My function is very simple:

```
const which_min = function(array) {
   var lowest = 0;
   for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] < array[lowest]) lowest = i;
   }
   return lowest;
}
```

I want to test if my function tosses an error when no argument is passed to it. In my test folder I have a test file

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var expect = require('chai').expect;
describe('#which_min()', function() {
context('with incorrect arguments', function() {
    it('errorTest', function() {
      expect(function(){utils.which_min();}).to.throw(new TypeError("Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"))
    })
  })
})
```

But I get what I find to be a quite peculiar error:

```
AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw 'TypeError: Cannot read property \'length\' of undefined' but 'TypeError: Cannot read property \'length\' of undefined' was thrown
  + expected - actual
```

I really do not see the difference in what I expect and what I get - so why do I not pass the test here? I expect it to be something with quotation marks?

Thanks
/Kira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a new instance of `TypeError` to the `expect()` function, which means it will expect your `which_min()` function to throw that exact error instance (but it won't do that, it will throw another instance of the same error type with the same error message).

Try just passing the error string instead, so:

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var expect = require('chai').expect;
describe('#which_min()', function() {
context('with incorrect arguments', function() {
    it('errorTest', function() {
      expect(function(){utils.which_min();}).to.throw("Cannot read property 'length' of undefined")
    })
  })
})
```

In that case, Chai will expect any error type with the same error message to be thrown.

You could also choose to assert that the error is a `TypeError` like this:

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var expect = require('chai').expect;
describe('#which_min()', function() {
context('with incorrect arguments', function() {
    it('errorTest', function() {
      expect(function(){utils.which_min();}).to.throw(TypeError)
    })
  })
})
```

But then you aren't asserting that the error message is exactly what you expect.

Refer to the official Chai documentation here for more info:
https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw

**EDIT:**

As @Sree.Bh mentions, you can also pass both the expected type of the error and the expected error message to the `throw()` assertion, like so:

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var expect = require('chai').expect;
describe('#which_min()', function() {
context('with incorrect arguments', function() {
    it('errorTest', function() {
      expect(function(){utils.which_min();}).to.throw(TypeError, "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined")
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much - the whole instance thing was what I was missing I guess. 

I wonder what test you would think was the more correct way to do it? Testing on the error type, error message or both. Just to build up my personal 'good testing behavior"?

Comment: In this case you are probably fine to check both the type and the error message using the approach @Sree.Bh suggested. 

One thing to be aware of is that the error you are expecting here is not one you are throwing yourself from your own code. If e.g. the wording of the error message is changed in the future (which is beyond your control), your test will break.

To make this a bit more robust, you could check for empty/missing parameters in your `which_min()` function, and throw your own error instead. In that case you will control the error message and can align the assertion in your test

Answer (score 1):

Agree to @krisloekkegaard explanation why `expect(function(){utils.which_min();}).to.throw(new TypeError("Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"))` fails:

To check the 'error type' and the 'message', [use](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw):

```
expect(function () { utils.which_min(); })
.to.throw(TypeError, "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined");
```

Comment: Thank you - That works for me! 

I wonder what test you would think was the more correct way to do it? Testing on the error type, error message or both. Just to build up my personal 'good testing behavior"?

Comment: As a good testing practice in unit tests, I would prefer to test both: the type and the message.